# Session inside a PHP class

Tags: php, class, session

I'm trying to make a login system and I need to save the username and password from each user.
Then, I want to access the session and to use those details for my queries.  So my main question is:

**Can I access a session from a PHP class and if so, where do I define the `session_start()`?**

When I tried to write the `session_start()` in the first line of the page -> and to access the session it didn't work.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from {$table} WHERE {$param} = '{$id}' AND userid = {$_SESSION['id']}";
```

I couldn't access the `$_SESSION['id']` variable.

Comment: Can you paste more code? The code here is nothing to go on.

Comment: There is nothing to paste. I just want to know if i can use a session inside a php class. And if so, do i need to do something different then session_start() ?

Comment: You can start your session before any output has been sent, so basically before any HTML or any `echo`, `print` etc. statements

Comment: You can **access** the session data from the class. You **don't have to** start the session within the class. As long as the session was started, you'll have the access to `$_SESSION` variable (which is why it's called **superglobal**). Regular rules about sessions (and sending headers) apply - you can't start the session if you *had output already*.

Comment: To rephrase JamesHalsall:  You MUST start your session before any output has been sent.